# Count the number of characters between opening and closing '<' and '>' for an entire file

Tags: c#, algorithm, string

I would like to count the number of characters between opening and closing '<' and '>' for an entire file (e.g. `<tag>bla<tag> == 6`). I could always write a quick algo to do it, but I am curious to know if there is another way. Maybe Regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. What exactly do you mean by that? Are they nestable? Do you want to include nested parts?

Comment: A regular expression doesn't count anything, so probably not.

Comment: @Oli - but a regular expression could get all matches between < and > and it'd be a work of moments to add up the lengths of those...

Comment: If you know the positions of the `<` and `>` you can just subtract the first from the second, no regex needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could with regex do it like this:

```
var brackets = new char[] {'<', '>'};
int counter = 0;
foreach (var match in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(data, @"</?[^<>]+>"))
  counter += match.ToString().Trim(brackets).TrimStart('/').Length;
```

This also counts ending tags correctly if you happen to have those aswell.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably what you already had in mind, but:

```
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
        bool inbrackets = false;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char ch in s)
        {
            if (ch == '<')
                inbrackets = true;
            else if (ch == '>')
                inbrackets = false;
            else if (inbrackets)
                ++count;
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("count = " + count);
```

Update: If you want to handle embedded brackets, just use an int counter instead of a bool. Sorry, that's obvious, but just an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no nesting tags, and you have well formed input

```
var charcount = File.ReadAllText("C:\foo.txt").Split('<')
   .Select(x => x.IndexOf('>')).Where(x => x > 0).Sum();
```

If you have nesting or need error checking, obviously you're going to need to write something more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = new Regex("<([^<>]+?)>").Matches("<tag>bla<tag>")
                                  .Cast<Match>()
                                  .Sum(m => m.Value.Length - 2);
        = 6
```